# XHR as string not object returned from the rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

[EDIT SOLVED] I solved the problem it was an issue related to a remotipart gem. I used the following link: https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart/issues/77#issuecomment-20843889

I have this portion of code in my controller:

```
    if @contract.update_attributes(contract_params)
      Rails.logger.info("Contratto aggiornato con successo")
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {render partial: 'contracts/success', status: 200}
      end
    else
      @errors=@contract.errors

      respond_to do |format|
        # format.js { render 'strutturas/edit' }
        format.js {render partial: '/pages/shared/form_error', status: :unprocessable_entity, :locals => { :errors => @errors }}
      end

      Rails.logger.error("Problema nel salvataggio del contratto")
    end
```

This is the javascript:

```
$(document).on('ajax:error', '#upload_contract', function(evt, xhr, status, error) {
    $("#form_error").html(xhr.responseText);
    console.log("Errore");
    console.log(xhr);
});


$(document).on('ajax:success', '#upload_contract', function(evt, xhr, status, error){
    $("#contract_space").html(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log(evt);
});
```

In case the update_attributes fails no problem javascript get the xhr as an object and I can use xhr.responseText to display a message.

I don't understand why in case of ajax success the xhr is a string and not an object so xhr.responseText is undefined.

To me the two scenarios are the same and can't understand why they are doing different things.

The problem is obviously in case of success because the error case is working.

This is the log of the xhr (should be an object):

```
<head><script type="text/javascript">try{window.parent.document;}catch(err){document.domain=document.domain;}</script> </head><body><textarea data-type="text/javascript" data-status="200" data-statustext="OK">&lt;div class='col-md-10 col-md-offset-1'&gt;
  &lt;div class='spacer30'&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
  &lt;div class='alert alert-success'&gt;
    &lt;strong&gt;
      Il contratto è stato caricato con successo. I nostri operatori invieranno via email le credenziali di accesso una volta verificato il documento allegato. Per qualsiasi dubbio può contattare l'assistenza SHB via email:
      &lt;a href='mailto:info@shbooking.com'&gt;info@shbooking.com&lt;/a&gt;
    &lt;/strong&gt;
  &lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;spacer50&gt;&lt;/spacer50&gt;
</textarea></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you want that `.on('ajax:success'...){...}` to look more like:

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', '#upload_contract', function(evt, data, status, xhr){
    $("#contract_space").html(data);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(evt);
});
```

Where `data` will be HTML from the rendered partial.

Comment: Well I tried what you suggest but does not work. I still receive my html surrounded by a textarea (don't know where is coming from). I could not understand the different behaviour in case of success and failure. I updated the question with the output of the console.log(data)

Comment: I suspect the textarea is coming from a layout (since there also seems to be `head`, etc.). If you just want the partial (and nothing from a layout), you'll need to render with `layout: false`

Comment: I found the problem it is related to remotipart gem, in case of success wrap the response in a text area don't know why. Here the link: https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart/issues/77#issuecomment-20843889

Comment: Cool. Nice sleuthing. Sorry I couldn't help.